# PHP/Laravel can not resolve parent Class

Tags: php-7, laravel-5.5

Using **php 7**, **Laravel 5.5**. All **models** are in default ***app/*** folder, Prototype is in ***app/*** folder too. Nothing was moved

What is most frustrating - this worked all right for **controllers** (everything is in their default folders)

My Prototype Class:

```
class Prototype extends Model
{
    //other code
}
```

My child Class:

```
class Tree extends Prototype
{
    //other code
}
```

> Exception: 
>       include(/var/www/html/app/Prototypephp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I need help to fix this issue. Thanks!

Comment: After a few hrs of working over this issue solved it by moving Prototype Class to other namespace (and folder). Did the same to PrototypeController for code readability.
Most probably there is some bug in either php or laravel.

Comment: Can you close the issue or answer yourself and mark it as solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hrs of working over this issue solved it by moving Prototype Class to other namespace (and folder). Did the same to PrototypeController for code readability.